# “Astronomy images” vs. “astronomical images”

Tags: differences, adjectives

Are there any differences between the two?

A Google search says that *astronomy images* is much more used, but I think that *astronomical images* sounds better.

Comment: Any reasons to downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find *astronomical images* to be about twice as heavily used taking google results as the metric, and overwhelmingly so from an ngram comparison:
[image]

It is common for us to use nouns as adjectives, but it is restricted to some uses (though it *is* appropriate here) and is generally not done if an adjective form of the noun can be used. Hence we would indeed heavily favour *astronomical images* as the most appropriate form.

In the case of compound nouns, the opposite applies; it's permissible to use an adjectival form but more common to use the noun. Hence *radio astronomy images* would be more common than *radio astronomical images*, though some people's style does favour the latter.

While the above would indeed favour *astronomical images* very strongly over *astronomy images*, it is common to use a noun adjunct rather than an adjective in headline-style. This would indeed seem to account for many of those we can find on google, as they are frequently in titles like "ScienceDaily: Astronomy Images" and "Best astronomy images 2012" rather than in body text.

Comment: Sorry but I find [astronomy image](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22astronomy+images%22&hl=us) (450k) much more used than [astronomical](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22astronomical+images%22&hl=us)

Comment: I get "About 86,400 results" and "About 161,000 results" respectively. One reason to mistrust google results as meaningful here is that they aren't consistent in what they give to who, when. Another is they weigh toward favouring titles, which are more likely to be headline style, because something with "astronomy image" or "astronomical image" in the title is more likely to be about what you are searching for, rather than merely mentioning it. Yet another reason is that the way they stretch what you search for to add near-matches changes with different forms.

Comment: Well we can consider ngram much more accurate then

Comment: Than search results, yes, as they serve different purposes and this is closer to what we want. There remains several issues with ngrams, especially when phrases might appear in different contexts meaning we're not comparing like with like. I do think we're getting a reasonable picture here, though.

Comment: Please add a link to the ngrams, either before the picture or on the picture.

Comment: Using "astronomical images that" vs "astronomy images that" (in an attempt to avoid skewing due to things like 'When Lovell studied astronomy, images were of a far lower resolution' in a couple of Google searches gives a ratio of 10 : 1 (but I'd better say that the sample size isn't too high).

Comment: Corpus evidence shows an overwhelming preference for astronomical image(s). The COCA has 34 records for _astronomical image(s)_ and 10 for _astronomy image(s)_. The BNC has no records for any of them.

Comment: A picture of a scientist sitting at a desk looking at sky charts is an 'astronomy image' but not an 'astronomical image'.  Their referents overlap but aren't the same.

Comment: @kbelder: could you explain that ?

Comment: @kbelder that could be tenuously called an "astronomy image", but calling it an "astronomical image" would be just as tenuous; it's just as technically true in both cases, and just as far from what the phrase would lead you to expect.

Comment: Yes - it's obviously an 'astronomer image'.

Comment: 'Astronomy' is a science, and an astronomy image is an image related to that science.  Pictures of a telescope, for instance, could be an image of astronomy.  'Astronomical' refers to the actual objects in space studied by astronomy.  An image of a star is both an astronomy image and an astronomical image.  For instance, you can have an astronomy textbook, but it isn't an astronomical textbook.

Comment: @kbelder you can't have "an image of astronomy", you can have an image associated with astronomy in some way; generally those used in it, or of the objects it studies, more tenuously items associated with it (assuming you mean an astrological telescope, rather than a lower powered one, that aren't much used now that binoculars are available). The above applies to all of those. Textbooks are a different case because the convention has been to use noun adjuncts of books for some time (with *textbook* as a common term, just slightly younger).

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Astrological telescopes tend to distort reality somewhat. And kbelder must know that the prices of some textbooks are astronomical.

Comment: Guys we are going a bit OT. And sincerly I still don't get which form to use. Consider the phrase in this context: "I enjoy watching  [astronomical|astronomy] images"

Comment: "I enjoy looking at astronomical images." "I enjoy watching astronomical videos".

Answer (score 1):

I would understand *astronomical images* to mean pictures of the stars and planets. I’m not quite sure what *astronomy images* would be, but it’s not necessarily ungrammatical, since it is not at all unusual for one noun to modify another in English. I suppose it would mean images related in to astronomy some unspecified way.

Comment: I’m not quite sure what _astronomy images_ would be, but [the expression is] not necessarily ungrammatical ... Perhaps they're the colorless green ones.